# Running injected JavaScript from assets folder in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

[image]
[image] 
I am using `WEBVIEW` to show my web page from my application.

My webpage is a simple `HTML` file that is on the server, so to show my site, the application needs to download this `HTML` page, but there is no need to download other files like `CSS`, `JavaScript` and etc. because these files are in `assets folder`.

My application can easily inject the `CSS` files to the web page but can not run all of the `JavaScript` files. Some times my application runs all of the `JavaScript` files, but sometimes only half of the `JS` files can be run.

Why does it not run all of the `JS` files? (I open and close the app over and over to force it run all of the `JavaScript` files!).
[Tell me, if you need more codes]
I use API 18. 
I use these codes for injecting `JS` and `CSS` :

```
private void injectjs() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("jscript.js");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
                "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
                "script.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                "parent.appendChild(script)" +
                "})()");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

```
private void injectCSS() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("style.css");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
                "style.type = 'text/css';" +
                "style.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                "parent.appendChild(style)" +
                "})()");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

My HTML file on Internet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Exercise</title>
    <!-- templates -->
    <script type="text/template" id="activity-list-item-template">    
      <li><a href="#activity-details" identifier="<%= id %>"><%= date %> - <%= type %></a></li>
    </script>
    <!-- maximum scale added to stop zoom on select controls -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="activities">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Activities</h1>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="add" id="add-button">Add</a>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
          <!-- the contents of the list view will be rendered via the backbone view -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us some context in the HTML?

Comment: @Bloodyaugust I added HTML codes. Now you can check it.